# CALayer not showing on device / simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a custom UITextField which supports partial borders:

```
@import UIKit;

IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface TextField : UITextField

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBInspectable UIColor* borderColor;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable CGFloat borderWidth;

@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable BOOL topBorder;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable BOOL rightBorder;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable BOOL bottomBorder;
@property (nonatomic, assign) IBInspectable BOOL leftBorder;

@end
```

Each border is implemented as a CALayer:

```
@interface TextField ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) CALayer *topBorderLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CALayer *rightBorderLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CALayer *bottomBorderLayer;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CALayer *leftBorderLayer;

@end
```

When a `BOOL` value is set to `YES`, the relevant layer is created and added as a sublayer to the text field.

E.g. if we set `topBorder` to `YES`:

```
- (void)setTopBorder:(BOOL)topBorder
{
    if (topBorder) {
        self.topBorderLayer = [CALayer layer];
        self.topBorderLayer.backgroundColor = [self.borderColor CGColor];
        self.topBorderLayer.frame =
        CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.borderWidth);
        [self.layer addSublayer:self.topBorderLayer];
    } else {
        [self.topBorderLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
        self.topBorderLayer = nil;
    }

    _topBorder = topBorder;
}
```

Now, the question.

This is how IB renders my text field if I set all border properties to `YES`:

[image: ibrender]

And this is how the device / simulator renders it:

[image]

**The right border is not rendering**

Any idea why? 
Thanks in advance!

Source code is available here: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Zi0P4tch0/a7404027051f5bfd2159)

**Thoughts - I**

I'm using an empty UIView to create a padding.

```
 //Padding

 UIView *paddingView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:
                       CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, self.frame.size.height)];
 self.leftView = paddingView;
 self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Could it be the cause of the issue?

Comment: I suspect `self.frame.size.width`, can you use `self.bounds.size` instead?

Comment: @iphonic I've tried that, nothing changes unfortunately

Comment: Why are you using 4 layers when 1 layer could do the job?  Isn't it just a case of drawing 0 to 4 lines in the layer-drawing-code?

Comment: Are you using storyboard or Xib?

Comment: @RajeshMaurya I'm using a Xib.

Comment: `self.rightBorderLayer.frame =
            CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width - self.borderWidth,
                       0,
                       self.borderWidth,
                       self.frame.size.height);`

think `self.frame.size.width - self.borderWidth` == 0, and about your problem, try adding `self.borderWidth + 1` of the `self.rightBorderLayer.frame =
            CGRectMake(... `

Answer (score 1):

I've switched from **CALayer** to **CoreGraphics**.

It gets the job done.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    if (self.topBorder) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [self.borderColor CGColor] );
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.borderWidth);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    if (self.rightBorder) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [self.borderColor CGColor] );
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.borderWidth);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    if (self.bottomBorder) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMaxX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [self.borderColor CGColor] );
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.borderWidth);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }

    if (self.leftBorder) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMaxY(rect));
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, CGRectGetMinX(rect), CGRectGetMinY(rect));
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [self.borderColor CGColor] );
        CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.borderWidth);
        CGContextStrokePath(context);
    }
}
```

Now it renders correctly on both IB and device/simulator.